# Register a Jackson deserializer for a class and all subtypes

Tags: jackson

Is it possible to register a custom `JsonDeserializer` for a class and all subtypes?

I'm able to use the same deserializer but I have to register it for every subtype.

That is. Given A and subtypes A' and A'' I've to:

```
module.addDeserializer(A.class,deserializer)
module.addDeserializer(A'.class,deserializer)
module.addDeserializer(A''.class,deserializer)
```

It's possible to register the deserializer only once and make it applies to all subtypes like in custom serializers?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by default by the SimpleModule where your custom Deserializers end up. But you can achieve it by registering a custom Module.
Here is the code I use (`Identity` is being used instead of your placeholder `A`)

```
public class IdentityDeserializationModule extends SimpleModule {
  public IdentityDeserializationModule() {
    super();
    setDeserializers(new IdentityDeserializers());
  }
}

public class IdentityDeserializers extends SimpleDeserializers {
  public IdentityDeserializers() {
    super();
    _classMappings = new HashMap<>();
  }

  @Override
  @Nullable
  public JsonDeserializer<?> findBeanDeserializer(JavaType type, DeserializationConfig config,
      BeanDescription beanDesc) throws JsonMappingException {
    var classKey = new ClassKey(type.getRawClass());
    var deserializer = _classMappings.get(classKey);
    if (deserializer == null && type.isTypeOrSubTypeOf(Identity.class)) {
      deserializer = createDeserializer(type);
      _classMappings.put(classKey, deserializer);
    }
    return deserializer;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private IdentityDeserializer createDeserializer(JavaType type) {
    return new IdentityDeserializer((Class<? extends Identity<?>>) type.getRawClass());
  }
}
```

My IdentityDeserializer works by using the passed in Class to find and use the appropriate constructor, but the exact implementation is irrelevant to the question.

Don't forget to register the module with Jackson, like so:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new IdentityDeserializationModule())
```

If you register the module on the Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder, be aware that it will no longer automatically find and register any other modules, and you will have to manually declare them instead.

Explanation:
Jackson uses a `SimpleModule` which uses `SimpleSerializers` and `SimpleDeserializers`. Both of those classes hold a map of Class to `JsonSerializer` / `JsonDeserializer` (respectively)

However, their implementation defers slightly.

SimpleSerializers has a comment at the top that says:

> Type registrations are assumed to be general; meaning that
> registration of serializer for a supertype will also be used for
> handling subtypes, unless an exact match is found first.

Unfortunately for us, SimpleDeserializers has a comment that says:

> Unlike SimpleSerializers, this class does not currently support
> generic mappings; all mappings must be to exact declared
> deserialization type.

So the solution is 'simply' to make Jackson use our own version of SimpleDeserializers with our desired behavior. And in order to do that, we just have to register our own Module.